# Need To Access phpmyadmin On HostGator Addon Domain With Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I recently purchased a website and need to change the Wordpress admin details to begin making changes to the site. HostGator made the site an addon domain and I cannot get phpmyadmin to find the database for me to make the changes.

I could really use some help or workarounds so I can finally change this site over...

Comment: The most likely reason a database wouldn't show up in phpMyAdmin is if you're not logging in with the proper username and password. Double-check those and maybe contact HostGator support for help; this is probably something the deal with all the time (since they're the ones who set you up this way) and probably know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the database is visible in 'MySQL Databases'. If it is seen there, then you have to 
just log out of C-Panel and then Re-login back to C-Panel, and only then the databases would be visible in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If the database exists, it should show in PHPMyAdmin. Confirm that the database actually exists. If not, create it and import the backup you should have taken when transferring to HostGator.

If the database does exist, and it's not showing, this would be a matter for HostGator to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Go into phpMyAdmin (username and database name are the same thing, If it was automatically created copy and paste the long thing example: DB23324251, then putin the password you created) and go into the database and search for 'users'. Look for the user name. Go into the password field (that is encrypted) and replace it with a new encrypted password. Passwords are stored as MD5 hash, which means you need to go to a website and type in a new password and have it encrypted via MD5 hash. Here is one: http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/

once you copy and paste the new encrypted password and save it, login!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - a new DB created in cPanel wouldn't show up in phpMyAdmin. I spent an hour on it before realizing that the solution is to **log out of cPanel and then log back in and then access phpMyAdmin**.
Extremely bad implementation from Hostgator I would say.